# How do I get excact single quotes words from the sentence?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following text.

```
sent = c("circle took away the victim's soul and supposedly made it easier for him to accept death; it was the point of no return in the vory death ceremony.",
   "hard to see, but he's basically yelling and telling people do not accept these biscuits because they're no good. UNIDENTIFIED-MALE: They are very concerned",
   "the Christ's death, Cambodians can inflict that fate on me, I will accept it.", "Related: What to read about the Khmer RougeKhmer Rouge executioner found")
```

My output should be

```
victim's
he's
they're
Christ'
```

Comment: I edited your post to improve readability; please check that it is correct (your character vector `sent` was missing quotes and a comma).

Comment: And **why** should this be the output?

Comment: Please add the code you tried that does not work. Otherwise, we do not know where the issue is. Or the question will be closed as off-topic. Actually, I have just tested 2 solutions, but I am not sure which one you want as you have not even described what you mean by "word" here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
m <- gregexpr("[A-Za-z]+'[A-Za-z]+", sent, perl=T)
regmatches(sent, m)
```

Sample data:

```
sent = c("circle took away the victim's soul and supposedly made it easier for him to accept death; it was the point of no return in the vory death ceremony.",
         "hard to see, but he's basically yelling and telling people do not accept these biscuits because they're no good. UNIDENTIFIED-MALE: They are very concerned",
         "the Christ's death, Cambodians can inflict that fate on me, I will accept it.", "Related: What to read about the Khmer RougeKhmer Rouge executioner found")
```